# Is there a way to 'un-duplicate'?

Tags: support, exact-duplicates

There is a question on superuser  that i would like to have the answer to (i have a similar problem: [How to stitch planar images?](https://superuser.com/questions/617083/how-to-stitch-planar-images)). but the question is marked as duplicate by 5 users. i don't find the linked questions very helpful to solve the problem.

(its all about stitching pictures taken with Photo-Cameras - mine are overlapping computer generated planar  images)

- did i miss the answer? or
- is there a way to re open the question? "un-duplicate" or
- should i ask it again?

Comment: You can ask a new question. Link to the other questions (to show that you have read them) and explain why they don't answer your new question.

Comment: The key thing would be to clarify how/why planar stitching is different, explaining why the other answers don't apply.

Comment: It is worth pointing out, the example question you used, is a duplicate of multiple questions.  So please be more detailed then the author was of that linked question, otherwise your question, likely will be closed as a duplicate also.

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted in comments, the way to prevent your question from being marked as duplicate is to look at the possible duplicate answers, and then clearly note how their answers to not meet your needs.

This is not 100% proof. There are plenty of cases where people asking questions think the answer will be one way because of incorrect assumptions, and once we've corrected the assumptions the question might still be duplicate.

**...But...**

Doing your homework first will go a long way towards showing the community you have put some research into this and have valid reasons to know this is not a duplicate.

Or, to put it more succinctly: **Prove it isn't a duplicate.**

The community is generally open to being convinced.